# How to implement a javascript to the div element that is created in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this javascript from [this link](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).

I have created a new div element in javascript using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="idangerous.swiper-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swiper-demos.js"></script>
 value= VALUE_FROM_DB.split("||");
 for (k=0;k<value.length;k++)
 {
    if (value[0] == paramName1)
   {
      return unescape(value[k]);
      console.log("no of swipe views ");
   }
    var val = k+1;
    var superdiv = document.getElementById('swiper-wrapper');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'swiper-slide'+val;
    console.log("div name: "+divIdName);
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.setAttribute('class','swiper-slide');
    newdiv.style.width = "25%";
newdiv.style.height = "30%";
    superdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
    var cnt1 = '<div id="container" class="container"><span><img src="img/cause_'+val+'.png" style="float:left;"></span><div id="clinicals'+val+'" class="clinical"><span ><h5>'+value[k]+'</h5></span></div></div>';
    console.log("check value"+cnt1);
    document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt1;
    console.log("clinical values: "+value[k]);
console.log("processsing parameter loop ");
var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),i,val,params = searchString.split("&");
}
```

**html code**

```
<div id="swipe_body">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-threshold">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swiper-wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
.clinical       
{
    font-size:15px;text-justify:inter-word;margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;
}
.container
{
 background:url(img/value_bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-size:100% 100%; display:block; width:304px; height:250px;text-align:justify;
}
.container span
{
 width:auto; height:30%; display:block; overflow:hidden;float:left; 
}
```

the output comes like this

[image: current out put]

but i would like to get it like this

[image: before SWIPING]

on swiping i should get it like this

[image]

Please suggest me ways to solve this problem..

**EDIT:** I have given the following code after the style and before javascript.

```
</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/swiper-demos.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf=8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="idangerous.swiper-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper-demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
 var cnt1 = '<div id="container" class="container"><span><img    src="img/cause_'+val+'.png" style="float:left;"></span><div id="clinicals'+val+'" class="clinical"><span ><h5>'+value[k]+'</h5></span></div></div>';
 console.log("check value"+cnt1);
 document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt1;
 document.querySelector('.swiper-container');
```

i added this `document.querySelector('.swiper-container');` as well as

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{   var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
mode:'horizontal',loop: true
 });
```

The only improvement is that only the 1st slide is there, it's not swiping.

Comment: Where do you [initialise the swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php) after you created its contents?

Comment: Yes, what's that `swiper-demos.js` thing? The usage docs say you need one css and one js file.

Comment: @Bergi,please check the edit version.yeah i just now, read the file you have suggested to...so now I am confused,where should I have these 2 codes `document.querySelector('.swiper-container')`  and `var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
 speed:750, 
 mode:'vertical'
})` this second code looks like for **auto slide**.I am concluding this as there is a speed parameter.

Comment: @Bergi, or anyone who can Please suggest what should I do now...please

Comment: @Bergi,please help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Jquery in your code but only native javascript.

I recommend you to give a look at this plugin.http://plugins.jquery.com/jcarousel/
This is a jquery Carousel. I already used it and it's simple, well documented and flexible.
Click "view homepage" on the top right corner and check demos in the developper's page.

**EDIT** here a sample code using JCarousel to help you :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/skin/skin.css" />

<html>
    <body>
      <div id="swipe_body">
        <div class="swiper-container swiper-threshold" id="mycarousel">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swiper-wrapper">
              <div id="container1" class="container"><span><img...</span></div>';
              <div id="container2" class="container"><span><img...</span></div>';
              <div id="container3" class="container"><span><img...</span></div>';
              ... ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            // optional configuration goes here
       });
   });
</script>
```

As you can see, only 2 line of jquery to get this.
You can download `jquery.jcarousel.min.js` at the url given above. Just create your several conteners with the data from the server. Remember, avoid giving same `id` to differents elements

```
for (k=0;k<value.length;k++){
    ...
   var cnt1 = '<div id="container" cla
    ...
```

They will all have the same `id`.

Comment: TCHdvlp,thanks! I am not commmfortable with Jquery.I am new to Java Script.